# Fast API Python add parameter

Tags: python, decorator, fastapi

I have a simple incoming post request to my fast api app.

```
async def post(request: Request): 
 ... do something
```

I want to call a function and initialize a variable with content from the header when the request comes in and use it then inside the function. An idea was to use the decorator but maybe I am not family enough with python, I don't get it work.
What I want is something like that, does anyone know if this is possible?

```
class SimpleHandler:
  def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text

  def say_hello():
    return self.text


def getHandler(header):
  return SimpleHandler(header.header_attribute)

@app.post("/")
async def get_body(request: Request, simple_handler: getHandler(header)):
  result = simple_handler.say_hello()
  ...
  return result
```

Comment: Accessing the header is not the problem. I’m looking for a solution to initialize a variable by calling a function in the parameters of the function like in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a middleware: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/

Answer (score 0):

```
simple_handler:str = Depends(getHandler)
```